# Datatables Order by Metadata Filters - Most recent activated first

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a series of filters with my datatable that let me sort by table 'category' which pulls from a backend metadata source. Right now the table sorts by the category column(in my case the first column, the default);

My current (functional) search looks like. Class `search-category-clicked` is added when the filter is active.

```
function Search(userInput) {
    var categories = "";
    $(".search-category-clicked").each(function (index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            categories += '|';
        }
        categories += $(this).val();
    });
    table.column("#category").search(categories, true, false);
    table.search(userInput).draw();
}
```

## What I've Tried:

I've tried implementing a number of the API methods (turning ordering off, table.order, multiple table.search methods) with no good results compared to this. These are the actual search results I want just not ordered in the right way. Other ways have yielded not exact results or strange orders of results.

### What I Want:

User needs to be able to see the items in the category they just clicked first in the table instead of having to scroll / page to get to them.

Imagine pushing to an array and then popping off the category values to activate the search showing first popped category first in the table. Any way to do it like this?

## Avoid:

Going to the backend to sort the data and return it again.

Comment: have you tried a custom plug-in ?

Comment: @Sven.hig looking into it. If it's easy I will just write my own.